# OnApplyTemplate() not called between WP7.1 and WP8.0

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

Have a custom control which works fine in Windows Phone 7.0 and 7.1 which I've just upgraded to Windows Phone 8.0. However, the OnApplyTemplate() override is no longer being called. Has anybody experienced something similar?

Many thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

A day and a half later ...

... in AssemblyInfo.cs I changed:

[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en", UltimateResourceFallbackLocation.Satellite)]

to

[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute("en")]

and it now works. I've no idea why.